# Getting Google Chrome to Ignore IE Javascript

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, javascript

I'm creating a slideshow using javascript that fades images.  Awhile back, I discovered that to change the opacity of an image, I have to use a different API, depending on whether the page is viewed in Firefox or IE.

Firefox:

```
img.style.opacity = [value 0 to 1];
```

IE:

```
img.style.filter="progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity= [value 0 to 100] )";
```

So, currently, I use `<script LANGUAGE="JScript">` for code that is meant for IE.  This was [suggested in the Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Browser_Detection_and_Cross_Browser_Support#Using_SCRIPT_LANGUAGE_to_choose_the_browser_where_it_will_be_executed).

The problem:  Chrome thinks my `<script LANGUAGE="JScript">` code is valid, when it is not.

How to make Chrome ignore the code inside `<script LANGUAGE="JScript">` ?  Or how to make my opacity code cross-browser?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't want to use a library such as jQuery, you should use Conditional Comments to target IE:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
<!--[if IE]>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ie-only-scripts.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Then define a setOpacity function in `scripts.js`:

```
function setOpacity(element, value) {
    element.style.opacity = value;
}
```

Finally, overwrite that function definition in the `ie-only-scripts.js` file:

```
function setOpacity(element, value) {
    element.style.filter="progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=" + (value * 100) + ")";
}
```

As IE is the only browser to load the second script file, it has its own special version of the function, while other browsers get to do things properly ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Use a library, such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) or [scriptaculous](http://script.aculo.us/). They have cross browser animations and CSS built-in.

Comment: While it seems overkill to add 50 or 60 kB of overhead for a simple opacity animation, I'm upvoting this because I've used jQuery before and it is grand.  Thanks!

Comment: I agree that it's overkill for that thing alone. In my opinion, using a library is a good thing anyway, though. It will make all the event hooking and so on and so forth a lot cleaner. But then again, if you don't have that many javascripts on your site.. Depends on the situation :)

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to check within the javascript function whether the particular properties that IE or Firefox use exist, then set the appropriate one.  For instance:

```
function setOpacity(element, value) {
    if (typeof (element.style.opacity) != "undefined") {
        // This is for Firefox, Safari, Chrome, etc.
        element.style.opacity = value;
    }
    else if (typeof (element.style.filter) != "undefined") {
        // This is for IE.
        element.style.filter = "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=" + (value * 100) + ")";
    }
}
```

You do have to be aware if a particular browser happens to have both properties.  In this case, Google Chrome does have a filter property as well as an opacity property, but IE does not have an opacity property.  Thus, the ordering of the if clauses above will work for both browsers.